# Render popup at the centre of the screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am rendering partial views as follows

```
    $("#AddQkEnrolWaitlist").click(function () {
        replaceAjaxData('@Url.Action("QkEnrolAddWaitListDisplay", "QkEnrolWaitlist")', "QkEnrolAddWaitlist", 'Id', 0, '1');
        $('#AddQkEnrolWaitlistModal').modal({
            show: true
        });
    });
**    @* Pop up modal for Add Waitlist*@
<div class="container">
    <div id="AddQkEnrolWaitlistModal" class="addeditwaitlistmodal hide" ">
        <div id="QkEnrolAddWaitlist">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>**
```

And the css is

```
        .addeditwaitlistmodal {
      position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
  z-index:1050;
  width:650px;
   margin-left:-325px;
background-color:#fff;
border:1px solid #999;
border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 *border:1px solid #999;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
outline:0;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
-moz-background-clip:padding-box;
background-clip:padding-box
   }
```

I need to display the popup at the middle of the screen always regardless of the position of the button in the parent screen on which we are clicking to popup the window.If i set top,left it will vary when the screen resolution and length (when scroll bar) comes.

PLs help me
Vidya

Answer (score 0):

I think u have got ur code wrong.

check this link http://jsfiddle.net/dreadwarrior/3d7QC/12/

If you want to create dialog ur code should be like this

```
$('#AddQkEnrolWaitlistModal').dialog({
             modal: true,
        });
```